# Heroku/Devise confirmation link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have the confirmable module enabled and I can send e-mail from my application, but the link in the e-mail that a user receives appends localhost to the beginning of the url. If you remove that it confirms the user. How do I remove the unnecessary localhost from my link? Note: I am using heroku, with send grid enabled.

Answer (score 3):

sounds like you need to set

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.yourdomain.com' }
```

in your production.rb to be the value of your domain.